# Esempi di questo uso figurato di "scalino"

Tags: word-usage, mathematics

Nel racconto *Nichel* dal libro *Il sistema periodico*, di Primo Levi, ho letto (grassetto mio):

> L’idea mi venne come si accende una lampada, un giorno in cui mi capitò casualmente fra le mani un vecchio diagramma tutto impolverato, opera di qualche mio ignoto predecessore; riportava la perdita di peso dell’amianto delle Cave in funzione della temperatura. L’amianto perdeva un po’ d’acqua a 150°C, poi rimaneva apparentemente inalterato fin verso gli 800°C; qui si notava un brusco **scalino** con un calo di peso del 12 per cento, e l’autore aveva annotato: «diventa fragile».

Anche se l'ultima frase si può capire, l'uso di "scalino" ha attirato la mia attenzione. Sullo Zingarelli ho trovato questa accezione del termine

> **4** (fig.) Variazione rilevante in una successione di valori numerici

che penso sia quella che si addice al contesto.

Ho cercato in altri dizionari e, sorprendentemente, una definizione simile a questa non sono riuscita a trovarla.

Potresti fare alcuni esempi di uso di "scalino" con questo significato? Si tratta di un uso comune del vocabolo o è piuttosto un uso caratteristico di ambiti tecnici?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Poiché **scalino** è sinonimo di **gradino**, è usato per indicare in un grafico una brusca impennata (o una brusca diminuzione) dei valori rappresentati;
in matematica esiste proprio la [funzione gradino](https://it.wikipedia.org/wiki/Funzione_gradino_di_Heaviside);

nell'esempio sopra citato, c'è una brusca variazione di peso al variare della temperatura;

riporto un [esempio trovato sul web sull'inversione termica](http://www.margheritacampaniolo.it/meteo/inversione_termica.htm), dove vi è una brusca variazione di temperatura al variare della quota:

> Partendo dal suolo si possono avere delle zone dove si presentano strati di aria più calda del normale e questi si dispongono a mo’ di *scalino* ( una sorta di zona di transizione, più o meno brusca e  spessa ) nel quale la temperatura subisce un’impennata verso valori più alti.

E quest'altro esempio tratto dal libro [*La fisica reale. Teoria dei fotoni e degli elettroni*](https://books.google.es/books?id=O7bEDwAAQBAJ&pg=PA197&lpg=PA197&dq=scalino&source=bl&ots=_t3_NOpxja&sig=ACfU3U23JarR74FoyNtCjCwUTbA-8DLQqw&hl=it&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwiK_IHN487qAhVDA2MBHV7KAB04PBDoATAJegQIBhAB#v=onepage&q=scalino&f=false) :

> Alle bassissime temperature, in mancanza di attriti, i materiali però presentano le loro caratteristiche "intrinseche" determinando l'effetto "Hall quantistico" per cui le resistenze misurate presentano dei caratteristici valori a *scalino* che risultano multipli del rapporto h/e² e sono sperimentalmente "molto stabili"

Sicuramente è un vocabolo usato in ambito tecnico, ma comprensibile e adoperabile anche in uso comune.

Comment: Ah! Ho appena trovato [questo](http://www.treccani.it/enciclopedia/scalino_%28Dizionario-delle-Scienze-Fisiche%29/) (non avevo idea che la Treccani avesse un dizionario delle Scienze Fisiche), ma la frase della definizione è incompleta.

Comment: E anche [qui](https://books.google.es/books?id=4MfUAgAAQBAJ&pg=PA464&lpg=PA464&dq=scalino&source=bl&ots=rrwEUnAQDh&sig=ACfU3U3PiY9QK35NC4D98J5pyo9XsKBroA&hl=it&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwjD1bKM0MnqAhVgBGMBHfnHCks4ChDoATADegQIARAB#v=onepage&q=scalino&f=false). Quindi, a quanto pare, si usa anche "funzione scalino" o "funzione a scalino".

Comment: Anche in queste [note dell'Università di Milano](http://www.mat.unimi.it/users/gaeta/FM2/delta.pdf)  e queste [altre dell'Università di Bergamo](http://www00.unibg.it/dati/corsi/8618/30303-Controllo%2520Modulante.pdf)         appare "funzione scalino".